# Make button to fire Javascript only if @Html.EditorFor is equal to "Closed"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

In a MVC web project, I have a **save button** in a view that calls a javascript function when clicked:

`<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" name="action" onclick="Confirm()" />`

How can I make this button call the javascript function only if the status dropdown is set to selection "Closed"?

This is the **javascript**

```
function Confirm() {
var input = $("<input />");
input.attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "confirm_value");
    if (confirm("Do you want to save the ticket to the knowledge base archive?")) {
        input.val("Yes");
    } 
    else {
        input.val("No");
    }
$("form")[0].appendChild(input[0]);
}
```

This is the **HTML** code for the dropdown:

`@Html.LabelFor(model => model.vcStatus, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.vcStatus, Model.StatusList)

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.vcStatus, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>`

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can call a javascript method on save button and in javascript function check the status of dropdown